# Setting Android Studio's GRADLE_HOME

Tags: linux, android-studio, gradle, terminal, android-gradle-plugin

I installed Android Studio on Linux Mint 17.2, but when I open up a terminal window and echo $GRADLE_HOME, nothing is set. Should it be set? If it should be, how would I find where it is located so I can manually set it myself?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle installed via Android Studio will only be available only within Android Studio. I may be wrong here, since I never used Android Studio. However, if you want Gradle available outside of Android Studio you may have to install manually. Check out the Gradle [Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html). Once you installed set the Gradle home in /etc/environment file (There are several files in which you can set this, but this is my preference since it makes the variable available to all users). Add the installation location to that file. You may choose to install in a different location.

```
GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/gradle-2.13
```

After you add add bin location to PATH variable. Eg:

```
PATH=...:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

Since you are adding the GRADLE_HOME in /etc/environment file you may have to restart your PC after adding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the plugin installs Gradle. I'm not sure if they intend for you to use the installed one or to install a distinct one. I see various versions, so that is confusing as well. I'm wondering what is expected for Android developers. If you've never used Android Studio, although I appreciate the effort, you probably can't help me to know what the Android Studio developers expect. All the same, you may be very correct they expect me to install it independent of Android Studio. That's basically the question I have.

Comment: @Mitch I use IntelliJ. Android Studio built on top community version of IntelliJ. Difference is Android Studio heavily favors Gradle for Android project. So, I may not know the minute differences. Having said that, I am sure that you will not be able to use Android Studio's installation on the terminal. You can use that Gradle to run tasks using Gradle window or even possible to build tasks in Android Studio's terminal. But not outside of Andorid Studio. Why don't you give more information regarding actual tasks, which would be more helpful for me or others trying to answer your question.

Comment: I'm really just learning Gradle. I can see Gradle is installed after installing Android Studio. However, it is in multiple locations and I have no GRADLE_HOME environment variable, which a lot of instructions seem to suggest I have. It is quite possible Google expects you to install it again manually, they just don't mention that in the instructions AFAIK. Mostly for now it is for when I follow along with videos or tutorials while learning. However, later it may be for actual Android development use and having it installed correctly from Android Studio's perspective would be best.

Comment: I just installed it. There is no clear indication on how to get the version installed with Android Studio to work from the command line, so this works as long as you only need the 1 version and not multiple versions as Android Studio can.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Studio zip bundles gradle. After unpacking the zip it is located in `android-studio/gradle/gradle-x.x/bin` (assuming the unpack directory is `android-studio`). In my case with Android Studio 3.1 the gradle version was `gradle-4.4`
so setting `GRADLE_HOME` to `/path/to/unpackdir/gradle/gradle-4.4` should work. 
Then add `$GRADLE_HOME/bin` to your path and you should be set.
You might have to `chmod +x` `gradlew` (for example if you use cordova and want to install a plugin)